# Horrible number comes from nowhere

Tags: c++

Out of nowhere I get quite a big result for this function... It should be very simple, but I can't see it now.

```
double prob_calculator_t::pimpl_t::B_full_term() const
{
    double result = 0.0;
    for (uint32_t j=0, j_end=U; j<j_end; j++)
    {
        uint32_t inhabited_columns = doc->row_sums[j];
        // DEBUG
        cout << "inhabited_columns: " << inhabited_columns << endl;
        cout << "log_of_sum[j]: " << log_of_sum[j] << endl;
        cout << "sum_of_log[j]: " << sum_of_log[j] << endl;
        // end DEBUG
        result += ( -inhabited_columns * log( log_of_sum[j] ) + sum_of_log[ j ] );
        cout << "result: " << result << endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and where is the trace:

```
inhabited_columns: 1
log_of_sum[j]: 110.56
sum_of_log[j]: -2.81341
result: 2.02102e+10
inhabited_columns: 42
log_of_sum[j]: 110.56
sum_of_log[j]: -143.064
result: 4.04204e+10
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are those for `j` values zero and one?  Are you sure `log` is `std::log`?

Comment: I disagree with the 3 close votes. The question is well-written: good code, good output trace and the answer is subtle. And there are 5 upvotes on the question. Would the close voters care to explain in more detail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`inhabited_columns` is *unsigned* and I see a unary `-` just before it: `-inhabited_columns`.

(Note that unary `-` has a really high operator precedence; higher than `*` etc).

That is where your problem is! To quote Mike Seymour's answer:

> When you negate it, the result is still unsigned; the value is reduced
>   modulo 2<sup>32</sup> to give a large positive value.

One fix would be to write

```
-(inhabited_columns * log(log_of_sum[j]))
```

as then the negation will be carried out in floating point

Comment: And to think the answer was always right there, in your name ;)

Comment: This is typical of what happens when you violate the basic rule: the default type for numeric values is `int`.  And never, never use an unsigned type for a numeric value.  If you replace all of the `uint32_t` with `int`, the code would have been correct.

Comment: Good advice James. Perhaps that's why Java dropped unsigned types?

Comment: I read in an old optimization guide that unsigned integers were faster, but I agree that it is not relevant any longer.

Answer (score 6):

`inhabited_columns` is an unsigned type. When you negate it, the result is still unsigned; the value is reduced modulo 2<sup>32</sup> to give a large positive value.

You should change it to a sufficiently large signed type (maybe `int32_t`, if you're not going to have more than a couple of billion columns), or perhaps `double` since you're about to use it in double-precision arithmetic.